# How to distribute received data from a connected client to other connected clients while making use of mulithreading?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, server, client

I'm setting up a server with multiple clients.

### My case:

Server is distributing data to other clients when one of the clients sends data to the server.
when the server receives the data from one of the clients, the server will store the data in memory and  send it to the other clients.

### Problem:

i'm using multithreading to connect multiple clients to my server.
When the client sends data to the server, i don't know how to pass the data to the other "connected client threads".

Server.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = 3434;
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

            System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected");

                new ServerThread(socket).start();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

ServerThread.java

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    public Data data;
    public Bartender[] BartenderData;
    public Consumable[] consumableData;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);


            String text;

            do {
                text = reader.readLine();
                if (text != "bye")
                {
                   data = new Data();
                   Gson gson = new Gson();
                   data = gson.fromJson(text, Data.class);
                }
            } while (!text.equals("bye"));

            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

client.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView txtResult;
    public EditText txtInput;
    public TcpClient mTcpClient;
    public Data data;
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        txtInput = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        createSomeData();
        new ConnectTask().execute("");
    }
    public void btnSend(View view)
    {
        data = new Data();
        if (mTcpClient != null) {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage(new Gson().toJson(new Data()));
        }

    }

    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //response received from server
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            data = gson.fromJson(values[0], Data.class);
        }
    }

}
```

### My way of thinking:

1. Client sends data (in this case a object named "Data").
2. Server receives data and stores data in memory.
3. Server is passing data from the "connected client thread" to variables in the main thread.
4. Server Pass data from main thread to other "connected client Threads".
5. other clients are up-to-data.

Comment: You can store every socket in list and when one socket receive data，iterate the socket list to send receive data to other clients.

Answer (score 0):

- create a list to store socket.
- start thread to process client request.
- when receive message loop list(exclude current socket) to send message to other clients.

I modify you code like this:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private static List<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<>();
    private Socket socket;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        sockets.add(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // assume the data from client is a string  Hello Server
            String data = "Hello Server";
            // send data to other client
            for (Socket sc : sockets) {
                if (!sc.equals(socket)) {
                    sc.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its a nice way to send the messages to the other clients but i dont get the part where you fill your arraylist with sockets... how do you get all the known connected sockets?

Comment: in your main function where to accept connection `new ServerThread(socket).start();`